# Addind an auto increment to my url?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having issues trying to add some type of auto increment to my ajax url.

```
url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?page=('i')&&format=html'
var i = i +1;
```

I want it so that every time the scroller hits the bottom the page number will increase by one to pull the next set of results.

Any help or guidence?

Here is my full code just in case.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var is_loaded = true;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() -   jQuery(window).height()) {
            jQuery('div#loadMore').show();
            if(is_loaded){
                is_loaded = false;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',

                    url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?page=2&&format=html',

                    success: function(html) {
                        console.log(html);
                        is_loaded = true;
                        if(html){
                            jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                            jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
                        }else{
                            jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1  style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: concatenation here `url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?page=' + i + '&format=html'`

Comment: adding '+ i +' just loads the 1st page results over & over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't handle this counter the same as your `is_loaded` variable?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var is_loaded = true;
        **var nextPage = 2;**
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() -   jQuery(window).height()) {
                jQuery('div#loadMore').show();
                if(is_loaded){
                    is_loaded = false;
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',

                        **url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?page=' + nextPage + '&&format=html',**

                        success: function(html) {
                            console.log(html);
                            is_loaded = true;
                            **nextPage++;**
                            if(html){
                                jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                                jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
                            }else{
                                jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1  style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var is_loaded = true;
    var counter = 0; // initialize the counter variable
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() -   jQuery(window).height()) {
        counter++; // here the counter increases plus one asuming that the scroller hits the bottom the page
            jQuery('div#loadMore').show();
            if(is_loaded){
                is_loaded = false;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',

                    url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?page=' 
    + counter + '&format=html',

                    success: function(html) {
                        console.log(html);
                        is_loaded = true;
                        if(html){
                            jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                            jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
                        }else{
                            jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1  style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem, we are here to help other developers :)

Comment: Now that I have this working, I wanted to implement a validate form checker. There is a <? php include ?> on the main file... How could I make it so that if there are no selections on the form it will lazy load but if there are selections it will not.